# Web API: authorization or/and authentication

Tags: api, authentication, oauth, authorization, hmac

I created asp.net web api project. I need to add authorization or/and authentication. I've read a lot about OAuth, SAML, JWT, HMAC etc. and everytime I see author emphasizes that OAuth is not authentication and you need to differ authN from authZ. I'm a bit confusing because I don't understand:

1. when I need to use authentication (SSO, login/password) and when authorization(OAuth, tokens) for API?
2. are HMAC, JWT for authorization or for authentication? because they are signed and I can add userid to this token use like user identifier
3. what are real differences between authN workflow and authZ workflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OAuth can be also used to *authenticate users* using a *resource owner grant* (i.e. a client gets an *access token* providing an *user+password* credential).

The resulting *access token* is what you should call *authorization*, since it will contain info like claims describing permissions, permission masks or roles (it depends on what authorization scheme you implement in your solution).

A *JWT* (JSON Web Token) is just a JSON representation of both access token and any other associated info. *JWT* is the content of some authentication result which can be used to be authorized against some resources. Since the *JWT* contains an *access token*, if you're using basic authorization, you'll add an `Authorization` header to your requests: `Authorization: Bearer [your access token]`.

Comment: So client must be authenticated to get access_token. But requests for resources with this token in header is only authorization. Correct? About jwt: can I use jwt for both SSO and for OAuth?

Comment: @oblomov86 It's correct. About SSO, it has nothing to do with OAuth. For example, if you're going to implement SSO for Web, and all web sites are within the same parent domain (i.e. you're using subdomains), you can share an access token using a cookie easily

Comment: In case of applications for modile devices bearer access_tokens is the best option?

Comment: @oblomov86 It's not only the best option but it's the easiest approach, isn't it? It's just about adding a header to any HTTP request :D

Comment: Fro instance, I add userid and role claims to access_token then sign and encrypt it. Can I use this oauth token for SSO authentication?

Comment: @oblomov86 With OAuth2 you don't need to encrypt the token yourself, it entirely relies on SSL/TSL , or any transport-level security. Anyway you can encrypt it yourself, but I recommend that either way you transport your data over SSL.